# как переключаться между активностями вне моего приложения?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent, main

, когда активность передается "третьему" (стороннему) приложению... Как вернуться на главную страницу, через стороннею активность. Пример:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)

        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
```

Открывается Гугл календарь. Как из него перейти на главную "активити" моего приложения?

Comment: или как использовать два `startActivityForResult(intent,1);` в одном классе?

Comment: "Переключаться" нужно в своём приложении, либо до перехода в календарь, либо по возвращению.